# Question about "Beloved one"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

In my English textbook was a sentence, 
"One person decided to get a new cat to replace a beloved one that had recently died"

This "beloved one" is his cat or his wife or husband?

Comment: It seems to me that we sometimes refer to relatives as "loved ones," not "beloved ones."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not entirely clear from the sentence, the use of the word "new" leads me to believe it is an old cat that is being replaced. If I were getting a cat to replace a deceased wife, I would probably just call it "a cat", as saying "a new cat" seems to contrast with a previous cat.

Answer (score 1):

It could refer to either, and without further context there is no way of definitively saying which.

Comment: This answer would serve better as a comment. Please earn some reputation points and then you can make comments.